# why is NaClO 'liquid chlorine'?

Tags: nomenclature

[image: enter link description here]

Sodium hypochlorite. $\ce{NaOCl}$.

Appears to be: one part sodium, one part chlorine, one part oxygen.

Five questions:

> - Couldn't it just as easily be 'liquid sodium' or 'liquid oxygen'?
> - It's not really any of these though, is it?
> - It's a compound of all 3, right?
> - So, doesn't the new molecule have it's own properties?
> - Or is a compound/molecule(s) properties simply derived from it's constituent elements?

Comment: It is just a sale trick.

Comment: yes perhaps, but the questions it led me to are real

Comment: which of my assumptipns are correct? which are not?

Comment: If a question is asked on Chemistry SE site, then, in contrary to sites like Quora, it is expected from the author to elaborate the topic of the question by doing at least basic own topic review, writing what he/she has found and understood, and what is the stumble stone. The quick questions without explicitly expressed particular effort are not very welcome, and may be closed.

Comment: I've once met that $\ce{H2O2}$ was called as "hydrogen"... unfortunately, this crap attitude is quite common from company PRs.

Comment: @voices For future reference: wikipedia contains many articles about chemicals, and for many of the inorganic ones (like NaClO), the search box permits _both_ a search by chemical name, _or alternatively_ by sum formula (try for example NaOCl2, or NaOCl3, or NaClO4). There equally is a site (http://www.cheminfo.org/wikipedia/) to retrieve 17k wikipedia entries based by a (sub)structure, especially helpful for organic compounds, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chemist would not refer to sodium hypochlorite solution as ‘liquid chlorine’ – the term is instead reserved for chlorine that has been cooled to below $\pu{35^\circ C}$ and has thus condensed to a yellow liquid. The easiest way to prepare it is probably to cool a container to $\pu{-78^\circ C}$ using dry ice and acetone and pass chlorine gas through said container.

Analogously, *liquid X* to a chemist means compound X in liquid state. Liquid nitrogen is probably one of the most well-known and most-used compounds where the state is explicitly mentioned – it does make a difference whether you are talking about a supercooled liquid at $\pu{-196^\circ C}$ or an inert gas at room temperature.

Thus, liquid oxygen is a blueish paramagnetic liquid that boils at $\pu{-183^\circ C}$. It is always on a chemist’s mind if they’re using a vacuum pump with a cooling trap cooled by liquid nitrogen as liquid nitrogen is cold enough to condense oxygen and any organic compounds can react vigorously even at very low temperatures with liquid oxygen.

Somewhat differently, liquid sodium requires elevated temperatures of $\pu{98^\circ C}$ – and very likely an inert gas atmosphere as it can react exothermically with ambient oxygen or water (vapour).

---

As you correctly assume, sodium hypochlorite is a compound with the formula $\ce{NaOCl}$ and like other multi-element compounds its properties have little in common with the elements that make it up. In this case, elemental sodium is a metal while elemental oxygen and chlorine are (molecular) gases but the compound is ionic with a sodium cation and a hypochlorite anion (which itself is a molecular ion made up of an oxygen and a chlorine atom). But that leaves the question why it is referred to as *liquid chlorine* by the manufacturer?

The main uses of sodium hypochlorite are bleaching and disinfecting and both of these derive from the same property. The hypochlorite anion is inherently unstable and tends to decompose depending on the conditions it is subjected to. The decomposition usually leads to chlorine gas being liberated which remains dissolved. Thus, you get chlorinated water. As you can smell chlorine from a hypochlorite solution and since the solution is typically produced by dissolving chlorine gas in a base (see Poutnik’s answer for details), you have essentially ‘captured’ the chlorine ‘in liquid form’ and thus an arguably acceptable common name would be: ‘liquid chlorine’.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:
No. No. Yes. Yes. No.
Next time, try searching before posting.

Longer answer:
It is just a sale trick. Chemistry community has no direct influence on used trademarks of commercial products. Some may call whiskey "liquid gold", but nobody expects there is any gold there.

The product is called "liquid chlorine" just because it shares some of characteristics of chlorine dissolved in water/water based solutions. As in both cases , there are some equilibrium concentrations of hypochlorous acid, free chlorine and atomic oxygen.

The "liquid chlorine" is basically a solution of sodium hypochlorite, sodium chloride and sodium hydroxide. There is the answer directly on the photo: "130 g/L available chlorine(Cl) present as sodium hypochlorite". I.e. chlorine is not present in its free form, but in chemically alternative form of hypochlorite, that can release chlorine at different than storing conditions.

Sodium hypochlorite is produced by dissolution of chlorine in solution of sodium hydroxide:

$\ce{Cl2(g) + 2 NaOH(aq) -> H2O + NaCl(aq) + NaClO(aq)}\tag{1}$

If acidified, e.g. by sulphuric acid, the reaction (1) is reversed:

$\ce{H2SO4(aq) + NaCl(aq) + NaClO(aq) -> Na2SO4(aq) + Cl2(g) + H2O}\tag{2}$

If dissolved by about neutral solutions, reaction (2) happens in lower extent, as there occurs also

$$\ce{ClO-(aq) + H2O <=> OH-(aq) + HClO(aq)\tag{3a}}$$
$$\ce{HClO(aq) -> H+(aq) + Cl-(aq) + O(aq)\tag{3b}}$$

The atomic oxygen is reportedly the true desinfecting agens, rather then chlorine itself.